# what is the return type of printf

Tags: c, function, return-value

It may be stupid question, but i'm confused. That's why i'm clearing my doubt. yesterday, during my interview i got one question like

```
char ch="Hello";
printf("%d",printf("%s",ch));
```

I thought `printf` is a **void** type function, because i never seen `printf` function to assign to any variable. So, i told, it will show **compile error**. Since, compiler won't find return type `printf` function. But, i was wrong. And the output is **Hello5**. I'm really confuse, how this comes.

Comment: `char ch="Hello";` should probably be `char* ch="Hello";`

Comment: downvote was expected, but not as many as this. got only 1 comment and 2 answer. what about rest 3 ..???

Comment: @UmNyobe this has been asked, during my interview. i didn't asked this question myself.\

Comment: you didnt ask a real question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function fun() is returning an int, you are just not assigning it to anything. So the return value is being discarded as it is not assigned to anything.

printf by the way, is not a void function but returns the number of characters printed, which is 5 in case of "Hello".

Comment: about `printf`, i knew this. that's why, i have mentioned the output in my question.

Answer (score 3):

What you probably read "you need a l-value to accept the return of a function call"

For eg. in your code.

you cannot do

```
5 = fun();
```

because 5 is not an l-value.

However both of these are fine

```
int i;
i = fun(); // i is an l-value
```

or

```
fun(); // ignore the return value
```

Also, you need

```
char * str = "hello"; // you cannot allocate a string to a single char
```

And `void main()` is non-standard.

You need

```
int main()
```